# Combine and transform multiple flows into a single flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to develop some code that allows N producers to produce values and have a single consumer consume all of the flows and run a particular method when one/many of those flows change. As an example, my consumer handles ordering/sorting String values that get emitted by many different flows.

ProducerA:

```
private val _someFlow = MutableStateFlow("")
val someFlow = _someFlow 

fun someMethod(stringToEmit: String) {
    _someFlow.emit(stringToEmit) //wrapped in a coroutine
}
```

ProducerB:

```
private val _someFlow = MutableStateFlow("")
val someFlow = _someFlow

fun someMethod(stringToEmit: String) {
    _someFlow.emit(stringToEmit) //wrapped in a coroutine
}
```

Repeat the above pattern for any N number of flows.

How would I combine N flows from all of the producers in a single consumer, where I can do something like sort all of them an output the list of sorted flows?

It looks like Flow has the `combine` functions, which looks similar to what I want, but I would like to apply some function to all of the flows when one or more of them change. If a flow doesn't change, then just use its old value.

It seems like something like this might work:

```
val sorted = producerA.someFlow.combine(producerB.someFlow) { producerA, producerB -> 
    return sort(producerA, producerB)
}
```

But if I have N flows, how would the above `combine` scale to support that? Is this a use-case for something else other than Flow? I'd like to be flexible to allow the consumers to emit to their flows on whatever coroutine scope they would like.

Comment: There's a vararg version of `combine` but if your flows are of different types, you'll have to cast the parameters in the lambda.

Comment: @Tenfour04 They would have the same type. I guess I'm also curious if in the varargs version of `combine` do I need to have explicit lambda parameters? I.e. if I have 8 flows I am combining, I need to define 8 parameters in the lambda?

Comment: Here are all the variations of it. For the varargs version, the lambda parameter is an array. With five or fewer flows, there are specific overloads where you do get all the parameters with specific types. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html

Answer (score 1):

If your producer flows have the same type, there is a handy [`combine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) function, which accepts undefined number of flows:

```
inline fun <T, R> combine(vararg flows: Flow<T>, crossinline transform: suspend (Array<T>) -> R): Flow<R>
```

It combines the most recently emitted values by each flow into `Array`. Example:

```
combine(someFlow1, someFlow2, someFlow3, someFlow4) { result: Array<String> ->
    //... use result
}
```